# Complex numbers $(x+i)^{10}=i(x-1)^{10}$

Tags: complex-numbers

I need to find the complex number x which is a solution for this equation

$(x+i)^{10}=i(x-1)^{10}$

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Rewrite the equation as $\;\Bigl(\dfrac{x+i}{x-1}\Bigr)^{10}=i$. This leads to setting $\;u=\dfrac{x+i}{x-1}$.

Then solve $u^{10}=i$.

Finally solve $\dfrac{x+i}{x-1}=u$.

Comment: I would suggest putting how you got to those ideas in your answer. I see it, but it took me a moment to find it.

Comment: Oh! Was I so elliptic? I added details to my answer. Is that clear now?

Comment: Yes. Since this is an algebra problem, I would avoid skipping steps in algebra. Good answer though.